# Selenium locators - linkText and partialLinkText - Multiple instances of the same text

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I would like to know if there is a way to find the 2nd( or third, fourth, etc.) link on a page using By.partialLinkText or By.LinkText.

I need to be able to locate several links which contain the same "partial text".  I would like to have a while loop which would locate the first, then the second, and so on.  Is this possible?

Thank you,

Steve Archibald

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly is:-)Just use `WebDriver#findElements`, it will give you a `List` of all elements with that link text so you can iterate through them or just pick one under right index at once.

```
Element secondLink = driver.findElements(By.linkText("something")).get(1);
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  If you want it in a loop, use `List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.linkText("something")); for (WebElement element: elements){ element.doSomething(); }`

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you so much, Petr and MrTi.

Comment: Glad it helped you, it is custom on SO to upvote or accept answers you like:)